# Easy way to convert text columns to numeric

Tags: r, dplyr, dataset

I have this example dataset

```
x  <- c("hot", "cold", "warm", "hot", "hot")
y <- c("happy", "content", "happy", "sad", "annoyed")
df <- data.frame(x, y)
```

I want to find a quick way to convert the text to numbers, it doesn't matter which order the numbers are.

So the output would be:

```
x  y
1  1
2  2
3  1
1  3
1  4
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3):

With Base R:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.factor(x)))
df
#>   x y
#> 1 2 3
#> 2 1 2
#> 3 3 3
#> 4 2 4
#> 5 2 1
```

---

With `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)
df %>% map(as.factor) %>% map_dfc(as.numeric)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>       x     y
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     2     3
#> 2     1     2
#> 3     3     3
#> 4     2     4
#> 5     2     1
```

---

Keep track of the labels with `labelled`:

```
df <- df %>% map(as.factor) %>% map_dfc(labelled::to_labelled)
df
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>           x           y
#>   <dbl+lbl>   <dbl+lbl>
#> 1  2 [hot]  3 [happy]  
#> 2  1 [cold] 2 [content]
#> 3  3 [warm] 3 [happy]  
#> 4  2 [hot]  4 [sad]    
#> 5  2 [hot]  1 [annoyed]

df$x
#> <labelled<double>[5]>
#> [1] 2 1 3 2 2
#> 
#> Labels:
#>  value label
#>      1  cold
#>      2   hot
#>      3  warm
```

---

Or keep the numbers next to the original values in a new column:

```
df[paste0(names(df), "_num")] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(as.factor(x)))
df
#>      x       y x_num y_num
#> 1  hot   happy     2     3
#> 2 cold content     1     2
#> 3 warm   happy     3     3
#> 4  hot     sad     2     4
#> 5  hot annoyed     2     1
```

---

If you want to change only the character columns to numeric:

```
library(purrr)

df %>% map_if(is.character, as.factor) %>% map_dfc(as.numeric)
df %>% map_if(is.character, as.factor) %>% map_dfc(labelled::to_labelled)
```

Or choose them by name:

```
library(purrr)

cols <- c("x", "y") 

df %>% map_at(cols, as.factor) %>% map_dfc(as.numeric)
df %>% map_at(cols, as.factor) %>% map_dfc(labelled::to_labelled)
df[paste0(cols, "_num")] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) as.numeric(as.factor(x)))
```

Comment: Only problem is that the dataset I use has numerical columns already and it seems to be changing the value of those for some reason

Comment: The code is set to change all the columns into what you asked, as per your request. There are some specific columns you want to convert from character to numeric? All the character columns must be converted?

Comment: @user123231322 is it what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
newdf <- df %>% mutate(across(everything(),~as.numeric(as.factor(.))))
```

Output:

```
  x y
1 2 3
2 1 2
3 3 3
4 2 4
5 2 1
```

In order to see the values, you can try this:

```
#Code 2
newdf2 <- df %>% mutate(across(everything(),~as.factor(.))) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),.fns = list(value = ~ as.numeric(.))))
```

Output:

```
     x       y x_value y_value
1  hot   happy       2       3
2 cold content       1       2
3 warm   happy       3       3
4  hot     sad       2       4
5  hot annoyed       2       1
```

If we add a numeric variable, this should work:

```
#Code 3
newdf <- df %>% mutate(across(x:y,~as.factor(.))) %>%
  mutate(across(x:y,.fns = list(value = ~ as.numeric(.))))
```

Output:

```
     x       y number x_value y_value
1  hot   happy     10       2       3
2 cold content     20       1       2
3 warm   happy     30       3       3
4  hot     sad     40       2       4
5  hot annoyed     50       2       1
```

Comment: this works. Would there be a way to see what each number each string was given?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when I have numerical fields in the dataset already

Comment: @user123231322 In that case you should select only the variable you want to change like `mutate(across(x:y,.fns = list(value = ~ as.numeric(.))))`

Comment: @user123231322 I have added an update with a dummy numeric variable, so that you can see how to adjust the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `rapply`:

```
rapply(type.convert(df), function(x)as.integer(factor(x, unique(x))),'factor',how = 'replace')

  x y
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 1
4 1 3
5 1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) match(x, unique(x)))
```